# Eclipse Neon change name of servers but console pulldown does not reflect name?

Tags: eclipse

I have 6 different Tomcat instances which I name but the name does not show up on the pulldown that allows switching between output for each server. Seems like one should not have to do anything to cause this but if there is, please tell me what it is.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: Company-specifc info that I would prefer not to show. Is my question unclear?

Comment: it's not clear to me right away since I have no way to reproduce it right now. It might be clear to someone who can or works with the feature more frequently than I do.

Comment: I appreciate your looking at the question nonetheless. Reproducing it is easy: create two Tomcat instances, name the first Tom and the second Jerry. I observe that the pulldown only has Tomcat and Tomcat(1), no Tom or Jerry.